# parse JSON in objectiveC (SBJSON) objects and arrays

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, nsdictionary

So far I've discovered in JSON that everything enclosed in { } are objects (objC : NSDictionary) and anything enclosed in [ ] is an array (objC : NSArray).

I've read and re-read this article about the subject>
[How to parse JSON into Objective C - SBJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919249/how-to-parse-json-into-objective-c-sbjson)

I have a .json file with the data modeled like this:
http://elbee101.com/dummySchedule.json

...and now for the code:

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://elbee101.com/dummySchedule.json"]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *schedule = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSDictionary *day = [schedule objectForKey:@"day"];
NSArray *myList = [day objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"myList %@", myList);
NSArray *numLaps = [myList objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"numlaps%@ ",  numLaps);
```

I'm getting "myList (null)" and "numlaps (null)" from the above code?!@

The question: Can somebody please set me straight on the ordering of objects and arrays with respect to my json data? I want to drill down the tree so that I can access the 'day name', 'session starttime/endtime/sessionname', 'numlaps' & 'class' but I can't seem to get past the 'day' object/array(?)

Comment: If `SBJson` parser is only your concern then confirm me that do your `schedule` and `day` has the values in it (log them and check), or you can do the same using `NSJSONSerialization` with improved performance. And are you doing this from your main thread of application...

Comment: i am having one custom class to parse any json file so u need that

Comment: chiLLer, thanks for the response! 'json_string' has all the data, 'schedule' has 1 key/value pairs and 'day' has 0 key/value pairs.
As for the main thread of the application, no idea mate :) I'm really looking for an answer as per the other thread ie. top level "Schedule is an object, day is an attribute(?) of schedule, name is an array(?)" etc... I'm really in the deep end here and very new to obj-c programming!

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to as `schedule` is the object enclosed in the outermost `{}`. Try this:

```
NSDictionary *json = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSDictionary *schedule = [json objectForKey:@"schedule"];
```

Then continue as before.

Also, if you're on iOS 5 you can use the `NSJSONSerialization` class -- using it is pretty much the same, you might get better performance, and you don't have to worry about the hassles of using a third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

call this where ever u need to parse

```
NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
arr=[[Headparse getArrayFromUrl:@"http://elbee101.com/dummySchedule.json"] retain];
NSLog(@"%@",[arr description]);
[arr release];
```

write this method as custom class use when ever you need

```
+(NSMutableArray *) getArrayFromUrl: (NSString *)actionType
 {
NSMutableData *responseData1= [NSMutableData data] ;
responseData1 = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:actionType]];
// NSLog(@"%@",responseData1);
NSString *responseString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 //NSLog(@"REs:-->%@",responseString1);
//[responseData1 release];
responseData1 = nil;
NSMutableArray *responseArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
responseArray = (NSMutableArray *)[responseString1 JSONValue];
// NSLog(@"ghfchfvghv%@",responseArray);
[responseString1 release];
return responseArray;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the response Krishna, Hare Hare! first of all I'm using an ARC project so I've needed to remove the 'release' references, and then I removed the 'retain' and I was getting all number of errors such as Use of undeclared identifier "Headparse". I'm sure it works for you, but I'm not 100% as to how to tackle your suggestion?!@ :)

Comment: headparser is a class where i am using to call every time when ever the parsing needed like a custom class

Answer (score 0):

This is how i use `NSJsonSerialization` for parsing the json object.

```
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://elbee101.com/dummySchedule.json"]];
    NSError *err;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                          JSONObjectWithData:data
                          options:kNilOptions 
                          error:&err]; // 
    NSDictionary *schedule_dict = [json objectForKey:@"schedule"]; 
    NSArray *days = [schedule_dict objectForKey:@"day"];//Days Array from day Object
    NSDictionary *dayOne = [days objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDictionary *dayTwo = [days objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"THE DAY ONE : %@",dayOne);
    NSLog(@"THE DAY TWO : %@",dayTwo);
```

Hope this may help you ....**Note :** If you don't want to go with `NSJsonSerailization`(consider reading of [this](http://blog.skulptstudio.com/nsjsonserialization-vs-sbjson-performance)) ,but still the parsing of json data like above will applicable in your case too.