# How to access the my JSON in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I'm newbie in iOS. And I'm having a problem accessing my JSON file that I retrieve in my web app server.

**JSON:**

```
{
"content": [
{
"info": [
  {
   "type": "TEL",
   "label": "Call Phone",
   "id": "32d7da39-39cc-4319-ab76-e67db9385722"
  }
],
   "name": "myname",
   "title": "myname_title",
   "image": "",
}
],
   "timestamp": 1370491676,
   "error": "SUCCESS"
}
```

I convert NSData to JSON :

```
NSMutableDictionary *mydatas =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

When I'm using this code to retrieve the name:

```
NSString *name = [[mydatas objectForKey:@"content"] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

It terminate the program.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71e3240'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

content is an `NSArray`, not an `NSDictionary`. You need to use `NSArray` calls to retrieve the item in the `array`:

```
// Be sure to check that the array has at least one item or you'll throw an exception
NSArray *contentArray = [mydatas objectForKey:@"content"];
if ( contentArray.count > 0 ) {
   NSString *image = [contentArray[0] objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Include SBJSon Framework from [here](https://github.com/paytronix/SBJson)

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData: urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
    NSDictionary * mydatas = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSString *name = [[mydatas objectForKey:@"content"]objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using the SBJSON framework . https://github.com/stig/json-framework/.

Then refer following SO question :[How to parse JSON into Objective C - SBJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919249/how-to-parse-json-into-objective-c-sbjson) . This  will be  easy for you to parse this data.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *contentArray = [mydatas objectForKey:@"content"];

[contentArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   NSLog(@"name of content at index %i is == %@",idx,[obj valueForKey:@"name"]);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
NSString *name = [[[mydatas objectForKey:@"content"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your JSON I can say,

Your `mydatas` dictionary contains 3 keys which are  content, timestamp, error

The object for key content is an array. If you want to retrieve the object for key name you need to do the following

```
if([[mydatas objectForKey:@"content"] count]>0)
{
     NSString *name = [[[mydatas objectForKey:@"content"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"name"]; 
}
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

```
NSMutableDictionary *mydatas =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Save it to Array

```
NSArray *array = [mydatas objectForKey:@"content"];

for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dic setValue:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"info"] forKey:@"info"];
[someArray addObject:dic];

[typeArray addObject:[[dic valueForKey:@"info"] valueForKey:@"type"] valueForKey:@"name"]];
NSString * NameStr = [typeArray objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"String For Name : %@",NameStr);
[dic release];
}
```

Hope its Work!!!!!!!!!!!