# Parse a nested Json to NSDictionary in iOS

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I Have a nested `Json` :

```
[
    {
        "result":"1",
        "roleId":4
    },
    {
        "projectInfo":[
            {
                "result":true
            },
            {
                "Project":[
                    {
                        "ProjectId":5378,
                        "ProjectName":"ASAG",
                        "CountryId":146,
                        "ProjectGroupId":743,
                        "Description":"Axel Spinger AG"
                    },
                    {
                        "ProjectId":5402,
                        "ProjectName":"BIZ",
                        "CountryId":146,
                        "ProjectGroupId":759,
                        "Description":"Bizerba Win 7 BAU"
                    },
                    {
                        "ProjectId":5404,
                        "ProjectName":"BOM",
                        "CountryId":146,
                        "ProjectGroupId":743,
                        "Description":"Bombardier Transportation ThinApp Migration"
                    },
                    {
                        "ProjectId":5394,
                        "ProjectName":"REDBULL",
                        "CountryId":149,
                        "ProjectGroupId":762,
                        "Description":"Red Bull Mac Packaging"
                    },
                    {
                        "ProjectId":5397,
                        "ProjectName":"VHV",
                        "CountryId":146,
                        "ProjectGroupId":743,
                        "Description":"VHV Win7 Migration"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I need is to separate it into small pieces to get value of some specific key like this answer: [How to parse JSON into Objective C - SBJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919249/how-to-parse-json-into-objective-c-sbjson)

My code is :

```
SBJsonParser* jParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary* root = [jParser objectWithString:string];
NSDictionary* projectInfo = [root objectForKey:@"projectInfo"];
NSArray* projectList = [projectInfo objectForKey:@"Project"];
for (NSDictionary* project in projectList)
{
    NSString *content = [project objectForKey:@"ProjectId"];
    NSLog(@"%@", content);
}
```

But I got the error when trying to get `projectInfo` from root node. Is there anything wrong with my code ? Please provide me an example to split up my `JSON`. Any help would be great.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: What error did you get? Can you write?

Comment: The error is due to the (wrong) assumption that your root element is a dictionary, which in fact is an array of dictionaries

Comment: That's not "nested JSON", that's plain vanilla JSON.  You "parse" it with NSJSONSerialization (or, if you must, SBJSON).  This will give you an NSArray containing the other objects.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JSON contains like nested array. Just spit each content into a dictionary to get the result.

**Working Code:**

```
SBJsonParser* jParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSArray* root = [jParser objectWithString:string];

NSDictionary* projectDictionary = [root objectAtIndex:1];
NSArray* projectInfo = [projectDictionary objectForKey:@"projectInfo"];
NSDictionary* projectData = [projectInfo objectAtIndex:1];
NSDictionary *projectList = [projectData objectForKey:@"Project"];
NSLog(@"\n\n Result = %@",projectList
      );
for (NSDictionary* project in projectList)
{
    NSString *content = [project objectForKey:@"ProjectId"];
    NSLog(@"\n Project Id =%@", content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your JSON structure, your top level structure is an array, not a dictionary.

Try this:

```
SBJsonParser* jParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSArray* root = [jParser objectWithString:string];
NSDictionary* projectDictionary = [root objectAtIndex:1];
NSArray* projectInfo = [projectDictionary objectForKey:@"projectInfo"];
```

Comment: projectInfo is an array too.